# I have a large scene with a hierarchy of nested Empties. I need to select and delete all the objects under Empties with a specific name

Tags: objects, selection-tools, outliner, collections

I'm new to blender. I'm struggling with what seems like it should be a very simple task. I have a large scene(a level imported from a game) that has a lot(hundreds) of nested emptys, and geometry under them.

[image: blender hierarchy]

My goal is to "clean up" the scene, to delete all the unnecessary objects. Specifically, I want to find all the objects which have "WRAP" as a part of their name, select them, and delete them. I also need to learn  how to select all the children of the parent empty(recursively, so that if it has other empties under it, and objects under them, it all would get selected), so I could delete a whole "branch" of the tree.

For some reason it's really hard.

- I have tried Shift+G > Select children. It works if I select an empty with objects under it, but doesn't work if I'm trying to select an empty that has empties under it and objects under them.
- I tried Space > "Select Pattern" > *WRAP*. It doesn't seem to work, blender  gives me no feedback, just doesn't do anything. Maybe I'm using it wrong?
- I tried searching for "WRAP" in the outliner. It seems to filter all the objects I need correctly, but I can't figure out how to select them all to delete them. Besides, these are still the parent empties, I'd need to learn to delete their child objects.
- I tried Right Click > Select Hierarchy on a parent empty in the outliner. Just doesn't do anything.

Also all the names of the empties are grayed out for some reason(in the outliner). Sorry for the newbie question, but can you help me figure out what's up with that, and how do I make them as a normal part of the scene?

Can you guys please help me out?

([Link to download the scene](https://mega.nz/#!6K43hIDA))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be rather easy, if I didn't miss anything.

**Select and delete all**
Filter name through the *search bar*.
Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the search.
Select all, shortcut <kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>RMB</kbd> > Delete

[image]

**Delete hierarchy**
Deleting the whole hierarchy of empties for some reason doesn't work well in the outliner.
Just move your mouse over to the 3D viewport and it works well.
<kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Select Hierarchy*
<kbd>Delete Key</kbd> in the 3D viewport to delete selected.

[image]

The grayed out items are *hidden objects*.
To make them visible in your scene, use the outliner toggles:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, it solved everything, thank you so much!

Comment: @RayAlez Happy to help, good luck with your project :).