# Blender 2.8 How to delete hierarchy?

Tags: outliner

Blender 2.8 How to delete hierarchy in the outliner?
I've been searching for this.
I can't find a straight foward answer.

Can it be done?
How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete hierarchy along with the object to which it is parented](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186100/how-to-delete-hierarchy-along-with-the-object-to-which-it-is-parented)   or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162925/i-have-a-large-scene-with-a-hierarchy-of-nested-empties-i-need-to-select-and-de

Comment: You click on it with your right mouse button and select "delete". Works for everything except the Scene Collection, of course.

Comment: in Blender 2.83 it seems delete hierarchy isn't possible. 
But I tested in 2.91 the feature is there just like in ver 2.79.

Comment: It's definitely there in 2.83. If not, you might try to reset to factory via "File - Defaults - Load Factory Settings".